¿Cómo mejorar rendimiento en mi pagina web con Api?
En general me gustaría que me ayuden dándome consejos de como mejorar el rendimiento en general de una pagina web, en mi caso, esta pagina web consume muchas imágenes atreves de una api (TMDB), he intentado comprimir las imágenes, usar lazy loading, cambiar .jpg a .webp y solo a resultado en una mínima mejora de rendimiento.
La pagina en cuestión es un clon de Netflix: https://netfliclon.netlify.app/

Si hay algún experto en el tema que me de una mano se lo agradecería.

Que plataforma usaste para la web? Es un CMS? Además, yo no siento lenta la web, eso si, no hace nada, click y click y nada que hace esa web. Al final son solo imágenes o hace algo esa web? Tu principal imagen es de 2000x1125 px, pesa 125kb, 100kb mas de lo que pesan la mayoría de las imágenes que yo uso en webs...

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Léete esto: https://web.dev/articles/optimize-lcp#reduce-resource-load-time, pues tu problema tiene que ver con el "load time" de la imagen que te dice @OCHOA
